# Computing the Dirichlet Density

Tags: prime-numbers, dirichlet-series

I have been asked the following question. I'm not even sure where to start.

Compute the Dirichlet density of the set of all primes $p$ such that $2$, $-2$, and $-1$ are all squares modulo $p$.

Comment: Hint:  use quadratic reciprocity to reduce this to some congruence conditions on $p$.  (Note:  you don't need the full statement of reciprocity, just the description of which primes admit $\pm 2$ as a quadratic residue).

Comment: That makes sense. I have managed to get $2\equiv x^{2}\ (p)$. Does that then mean that $$\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=1?$$ where this is Legendre symbol. If so, is the same true for $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{-2}{p}\right)$?

Comment: Yes, you want all three of these to be $1$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks you. Do I then want to find the set of primes such that $2\equiv 1\mod{p}$? And the same for the others?

Comment: No....  you need to find the set of primes for which, say, $x^2\equiv 2\pmod p$ has a solution.  If you've never been through the theory of quadratic residues, this problem is going to be extremely difficult.  I'd start by reviewing the basics.

Comment: The [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) reviews the basics of the theory of quadratic residue, and includes specific discussion on the residues $\pm 2$ and $-1$.

Comment: Ok, that seems to help a lot. From The Quadratic Reciprocity Law, am I right in saying that $p\equiv\pm1\mod{8}$, since $$\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=\begin{cases} +1 & if\ p\equiv\pm1\mod{8}\\ -1 & if\ p\equiv\pm3\mod{8} \end{cases}?$$

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Thank you. So I now have $p\equiv\pm1\mod{8}$ from $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)$ and $p\equiv1\mod{4}$ from $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)$. What can I obtain from $\left(\frac{-2}{p}\right)$?

Comment: Well, A.  the case of $-2$ is handled in the wiki article I linked to.  and B.  you don't need it.  If $2$ and $-1$ are both quadratic residues then so is $-2$.

Comment: I thought so, very confusing. Thank you for helping. Am I also right in saying (and is it helpful) that the set of primes congruent to $1$ modulo $8$ is a subset of the primes which are congruent to the primes congruent to $1$ modulo $4$? So I only really need to consider $p\equiv1\mod{4}$ and $p\equiv-1\mod{8}$.

Comment: No, that last bit is wrong.  You need to satisfy both congruences simultaneously.  That is you need $p\equiv \pm 1 \pmod 8$ AND $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  Hint:  your goal is to write this as a single congruence.

Comment: How can both $p\equiv-1(\mod{8})$ and $p\equiv1(\mod{4})$ be satisfied simultaneously?

Comment: they can't, that's the point.  But $p\equiv 1 \pmod 8$ AND $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ can.

Comment: If you get confused, it's always good to work examples. Take $p=7$.  That's $-1 \pmod 8$ so $2$ is meant to be a square.  Sure enough $3^2\equiv 2 \pmod 7$.  However, $-1$ meant not to be a square.  Well, that's easily confirmed (by trial and error if nothing else).  Thus $7$ fails.  Now try $p=17$ (smallest example congruent to $1$ modulo both $4$ and $8$).

Comment: Ok, I have done that and it make things a little clearer. Aren't the primes which satisfy both conditions exactly those primes which satisfy $p\equiv1\mod{8}$ though?

Comment: Yes!  That's what I meant by saying you need to get it down to a single congruence.

Comment: At this point, you should be able to quickly get the answer to the original question, no?

Comment: Oh ok, that is a great help. Thank you. I think I can manage from this point (I know I'm not far away). I just need to calculate the density of the set of prime $\{p\in\mathcal{P}:p=1+8x,x\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.