# Dirichlet density of $p \equiv 1 \bmod 8$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, dirichlet-series

I am pretty new to this website although it looks really useful. Could someone help me please? My question is that same as this one: [Computing the Dirichlet Density](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170749/computing-the-dirichlet-density)

I can't work out how to calculate the density of the prime numbers which are congruent to $1$ modulo $8$ (I tried to comment but you need reputation). I know the density of primes congruent to $1$ modulo $4$ is $\frac{1}{2}$. Does that help?

Thanks.

Comment: Can a more knowledgeable user tell me if this article is relevant here? https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Dirichlet_density

Answer (score 1):

It is $1/\varphi(8) = 1/4$ where $\varphi \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is the Euler totient function. You need to take a closer look at the proof of Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions.

Comment: in particular the step $\sum_{n \equiv 1 \bmod 8} \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log n} n^{-s} = \frac{1}{\varphi(8)} \sum_{\chi \bmod 8} \log L(s,\chi)$