# Dirichlet density of set of primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

How to find the Dirichlet density of the set of  primes which are congruent to 2 mod 3 and 5 mod 7

And the set of primes which congruent to 1 mod 9 but not to 1 mod 27
I can't understand the processes of evaluating this using slur function?

Answer (score 2):

The Dirichlet density of primes congruent to $a$ modulo $m$ is $\frac{1}{\phi(m)}$ for $\gcd(a,m)=1$.

Other posts with this topic:

[Dirichlet density of $p \equiv 1 \bmod 8$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170888/dirichlet-density-of-p-equiv-1-bmod-8)

Comment: Yes but the problem is they want both in the first case and one only in the second so who to combin them in the formula @Dietrich Burde

Comment: @Rosa: for $2\mod 3$ combined with $5\mod 7$, this is $5\mod 21$ by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  Doing similar processes for $1\mod 9$, we get that $10\mod 27$ and $19\mod 27$ meet the other criteria.